# How to bind .hover() to dynamically created "li" elemtent?

Tags: jquery

All the solutions I was able to find suggests to use `.live()` method. But as of today it is deprecated.

`.hover()` works perfectly on "li" elements not created dynamically. But once I append new "li" `.hover()` is not triggered at all.

Anybody has figured this one out?

Comment: Unlike the original question this is a "duplicate" of, the accepted answer to this question works.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The "hover" event has been deprecated with delegated event handling such as `.on()` per the [`.on()` jQuery doc pages](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Instead, you need to use `.on()` delegated event handling with mouseenter and mouseleave and an event handler for each.

For example:

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", "li", function() {
    // hover starts code here
});

$(document).on("mouseleave", "li", function() {
    // hover ends code here
});
```

In your real code, you would select a static parent object that is much closer to the dynamic `li` tags than the `document` object for better performance.

Comment: So, I guess it just confirms what I have suspected:( Thank you for your quick and direct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Edit: Sry missed the deprecated event

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", "li", function(){
       //Your code
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/live/

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bTJjE/)

Comment: This gives you only one function and has been deprecated as of jQuery 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

Use [JQuery On](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
Try this :

```
$(document).on('hover', 'li', function () {

});
```

Comment: This gives you only one function and has been deprecated as of jQuery 1.8.